# select from 2 table and make ordering them

Tags: php, mysql

first, sorry for my English ...
what i want is to select from two SQL tables and then make them in a specific order , like in forums ...
i have two table, topic and users, i want to select from both of them a putt author info next to his topic
here is the SQL of Topic and users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the php code might look like this

---

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query(' MySQL query ... ');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['username']'<br>';
    echo $row['message'].'<br></p>';
}
?>
```

is there any way to do it ??

Comment: try this....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229239/php-mysql-select-from-2-different-tables-and-display-the-data-mixed-together-o

Comment: didn't work, it's really complicated, i m looking for something simple, but thanks

Comment: but u should try it, and show us your "tries"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, what you are looking for is the correct SQL statement to execute. The following simple solution will.

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT users.username, topics.message FROM `users` INNER JOIN topics ON topics.author_id = users.id');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<p>'.$row['username']'<br>';
        echo $row['message'].'<br></p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN topics ON topics.author_id = users.id'
```